# Has the CERN LHC Muon Detector caused mini singularities within Earths atmosphere?

Tags: physics, astronomy, time, big-bang-theory, quantum-mechanics

"Something very interesting happened at CERN recently – they had an accident.  The accident created a “rainbow” universe.  What does this mean, exactly?  CERN actually created a universe for 2.6 seconds."

http://yournewswire.com/cern-had-an-accident-it-created-a-rainbow-universe/

Comment: Some other articles on this website give you an idea what kind of site it is, e.g. "Does CERN Host The Real CIA Headquarters?", "CIA Admit To Using Weather Modification As A Military Weapon", "Disturbing Report: CERN’s LHC Might Attract Asteroids To Earth", "Mysterious Clouds Over CERN May Be ‘Portal To Other Dimensions’". Enough said?

Answer (score 9):

This is based on an April Fools joke posted on the NOVA Next blog, April 1, 2015.

http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/physics/lhc-accidental-rainbow-universe/

"Jessica Czerniski", who is quoted in the article, is a made-up name, and all Google hits for that name lead to copies of this article.  I found no other indication of anyone by that name having actually worked at CERN.

Comment: How would you prounce "Czerniski"? Like CERN?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Yeah, I think [that's the joke](https://earldouglas.com/diversions/thats-the-joke/thats-the-joke.jpg).